# String Compression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, substring

I have the following input :

```
 my_list = ["x d1","y d1","z d2","t d2"]
```

And would like to transform it into :

```
Expected_result = ["d1(x,y)","d2(z,t)"]
```

I had to use brute force, and also had to call pandas to my rescue, since I didn't find any way to do it in plain/vanilla python. Do you have any other way to solve this?

```
import pandas as pd 

my_list = ["x d1","y d1","z d2","t d2"]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list,columns=["col1"])

df2 = df["col1"].str.split(" ",expand = True)
df2.columns = ["col1","col2"]
grp = df2.groupby(["col2"])

result = []
for grp_name, data in grp:
  res =  grp_name +"(" + ",".join(list(data["col1"])) + ")"
  result.append(res)
print(result)
```

Comment: Your requirements are not made clear in the question. You mention in comments below that you want to handle cases like `["x d1", "y d1", "z d1"]`. What about `["x d1", "y d1", "t d2", "z d1", "u d2"]`? What other cases should be handled?

Comment: ["x d1", "y d1", "t d2", "z d1", "u d2"] is not and edge condition. it falls into general case and the result will be ['d1(x,y,z)', 'd2(t,u)']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The code defines an empty dictionary.
2. It then iterates over each item in your list and uses the `split()` method to split item into a `key` and a `value`.
3. Then uses the [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method to add the `key` and the `value` to the empty dictionary. If the `value` already exists as a `key` in the dictionary, it appends the `key` to that value's existing list of keys. And if the `value` does not exist as a key in the dictionary, it creates a new key-value pair with the value as the key and the key as the first element in the new list.
4. Finally, the list comprehension iterates over the items in the dictionary and creates a string for each key-value pair using `join()` method to concatenate the keys in the value list into a single string.

```py
result = {}

for item in my_list:
    key, value = item.split()
    result.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
    
output = [f"{k}({', '.join(v)})" for k, v in result.items()]
print(output)
```

---

```
['d1(x, y)', 'd2(z, t)']
```

Comment: You can replace the `if` and the 2 lines following it by a single `result.setdefault(value, []).append(key)` (also, inverting the variable names might be more meaningful) ;)

Comment: I agree that the name of the variables should be changed like this: 

for item in my_list:    
    value, key = item.split()
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

Also, Would you mind explaining a little bit about how this line works? 

result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

Since this is the crux of the algorithm

Comment: I added some explanation to the answer which you can refer to. I hope that helps @ShckTchamna

Answer (score 2):

**If your values are already sorted by key** (d1, d2), you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

out = [f"{k}({','.join(x[0] for x in g)})"
       for k, g in groupby(map(str.split, my_list), lambda x: x[1])]
```

Output:

```
['d1(x,y)', 'd2(z,t)']
```

Otherwise you should use a dictionary [as shown by @Jamiu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75192288/16343464).

A variant of your pandas solution:

```
out = (df['col1'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
       .groupby(1)[0]
       .apply(lambda g: f"{g.name}({','.join(g)})")
       .tolist()
      )
```

Comment: `itertools` is definitely a good toolbox. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75192610/15239951 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ["x d1","y d1","z d2","t d2"]
res = []
 
for item in my_list:

    a, b, *_ = item.split()
 
    if len(res) and b in res[-1]:
            res[-1] = res[-1].replace(')', f',{a})')
    else:
        res.append(f'{b}({a})')

print(res)
['d1(x,y)', 'd2(z,t)']
```

Let N be the number that follows d, this code works for any number of elements within dN, as long as N is ordered, that is, d1 comes before d2, which comes before d3, ... Works with any value of N , and you can use any letter in the d link as long as it has whatever value is in dN and then dN, keeping that order, "val_in_dN dN"

If you need something that works even if the dN are not in sequence, just say the word, but it will cost a little more

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which is based on `pandas`:

```
(pd.DataFrame(np.array([str.split(x, ' ') for x in my_list]), columns=['b', 'a'])
 .groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: f'({x.values[0]}, {x.values[1]})')
 .reset_index().sum(axis=1).tolist())
```

---

Output:

```
['d1(x, y)', 'd2(z, t)']
```

---

**EDIT**

The OP, @ShckTchamna, would like to see the above solution modified, in order to be more general: The reason of this edit is to provide a solution that works with the example the OP gives in his comment below.

```
my_list = ["x d1","y d1","z d2","t d2","kk d2","m d3", "n d3", "s d4"] 

(pd.DataFrame(np.array([str.split(x, ' ') for x in my_list]), columns=['b', 'a'])
 .groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: f'({",".join(x.values)})')
 .reset_index().sum(axis=1).tolist())
```

Output:

```
['d1(x,y)', 'd2(z,t,kk)', 'd3(m,n)', 'd4(s)']
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I upvoted it. However, it seems your solution should be refined in order to make it more generalize. For example:
Try the following :

Input: my_list = ["x d1","y d1","z d2","t d2","kk d2","m d3", "n d3", "s d4"]

Expected Output = ['d1(x,y)', 'd2(z,t,kk)', 'd3(m,n)', 'd4(s)']

Comment: Thanks, @ShckTchamna, for commenting my solution and for upvoting. I will soon add a way to deal with the situation you indicate (busy at the moment).

Answer (score -1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[e.split(' ') for e in ["x d1","y d1","z d2","t d2"]])
r = (df.groupby(1)
       .apply(lambda r:"{0}({1},{2})".format(r.iloc[0,1], r.iloc[0,0], r.iloc[1,0]))
       .reset_index()
       .rename({1:"points", 0:"coordinates"}, axis=1)
         )

print(r.coordinates.tolist())
# ['d1(x,y)', 'd2(z,t)']

print(r)
#   points coordinates
# 0    d1     d1(x,y)
# 1    d2     d2(z,t)
```

In replacement of my previous one (that works too) :

```py
import itertools as it

my_list = [e.split(' ') for e in ["x d1","y d1","z d2","t d2"]]

r=[]
for key, group in it.groupby(my_list, lambda x: x[1]):
    l=[e[0] for e in list(group)]
    r.append("{0}({1},{2})".format(key, l[0], l[1]))

print(r)
Output :

['d1(x,y)', 'd2(z,t)']
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I upvoted it. However, it seems your solution should be refined in order to make it more generalize. For example:
Try the following :

Input: my_list = ["x d1","y d1","z d2","t d2","kk d2","m d3", "n d3", "s d4"]

Expected Output = ['d1(x,y)', 'd2(z,t,kk)', 'd3(m,n)', 'd4(s)']

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am working on it.