# Counting consecutive numbers in a list and pick corresponding numbers at the same index from another list

Tags: python, list, compression

I want to count if consecutive numbers are the same in the first list. If the count is 1, I want to pick the corresponding number in the second list.

```
lst1 = [[500],[500], [500], [300], [500], [300], [300], [200]]
lst2 = [[10], [10.5], [10.7], [9], [10.1], [97], [10.2], [10.9]]



def trains(lst):
    element = []
    freque = []
    if not lst:
        return element
    count = 1
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i][0] == lst[i+1][0]:
            count += 1
        else:
            freque.append(count)
            element.append(lst[i][0])
            count = 1
    freque.append(count)
    element.append(lst[i+1][0])

    return element,freque

print(trains(lst1)) # = ([500, 300, 500, 300, 200], [3, 1, 1, 2, 1])
```

Eventually, I want the result to look like this:

```
[[300, 9], [500, 10.1], [200, 10.9]]
```

Comment: if you expect a list of lists as a result, why does your function return 2 separate lists?

Comment: coming from 500 to 300 why it does not add the corresponding element? `[300], [500], [300]` `[9], [10.1], [97]`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it doesn't have to be a list of lists so long I can extract those corresponding values.

Comment: you wrote that you "want the result to look like this" (list of lists)

Comment: RomanPerekhrest my bad.

Comment: maybe it's a bit late but can you try my answer with `zip_longest` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```py
lst1 = [[500],[500], [500], [300], [500], [300], [300], [200]]
lst2 = [[10], [10.5], [10.7], [9], [10.1], [97], [10.2], [10.9]]

def trains(lst1, lst2):
    result = []
    count = 1
    for i in range(1, len(lst1)):
        if lst1[i][0] == lst1[i-1][0]:
            count += 1
        else:
            if count == 1:
                result.append([lst1[i-1][0], lst2[i-1][0]])
            count = 1
    
    if count == 1:
        result.append([lst1[-1][0], lst2[-1][0]])
    return result

print(trains(lst1, lst2))
```

---

```
[[300, 9], [500, 10.1], [200, 10.9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

zippy = zip_longest(lst1, lst1[1:], lst1[2:], lst2, lst2[1:], lst[2:])
out = [[i1[0], j1[0]] for i0, i1, i2, j0, j1, j2 in zippy if (i1 != i0) & (i1 != i2)]
print(out)

# Output
[[300, 9], [500, 10.1], [200, 10.9]]
```